# Segmentation fault with strcmp()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, argv

```
if(strcmp(argv[2], NULL) == 0)
```

I'm passing 3 command line arguments but I also want to run it with only 2 command line arguments with the above statement. But a segmentation fault error is being displayed.

I also tried with

```
if(argc < 3)
```

but it also didn't work...same segmentation fault...

Comment: USe `if(argv[2] == NULL)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sorry but I think there's no grantee that what value would `argv[2]` have if `argc==2`. Please see my update in my answer.

Comment: @PengyuCHEN I comment on the bases of incorrect code only of-couse if unsufficent arguments passed then it will be out-of-bound error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why segmentation fault?

Because of code `if(strcmp(argv[2], NULL) == 0)`,   you are passing NULL as string pointer to `strcmp()` function; that try to deference at NULL to compare chars codes (e.g. acsii code) this cause undefined behavior at run time.

You should compare a string pointer with NULL using `==` as `if(argv[2] == NULL)`

> I'm passing 3 command line arguments but I also want to run it with only 2 command line arguments with the above statement.

You can implement this in two ways:

1. The main syntax is:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   ```

   The first argument `argc`  is argument counter that is total number of arguments passed to your process including process name.

   So when you pass no extra argument then `argc == 1` e.g. `./exe`

   Suppose if you pass three arguments as follows:

   ```
   ./exe firstname lastname
   ```

   Then `argc == 3`,
   it looks like you are passing two arguments but including executable name you are actually passing three arguments to process.

   So you can use of `argc` value to iterate in a loop to print arguments passed (other then executable)

   ```
    printf("Process name is: %s", argv[0]);
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++ ){
         printf("argv[%d] %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
   ```
2. Second technique is using second argument: `argv[]` is NULL terminated array of string strings so `argv[argc]` is always equals to NULL. You can use this information in loop to iterate and process of  arguments passed.

   To understand this suppose you are executing function as:

   ```
   ./exe firstname lastname
   ```

   then `argv[0] == ./exe`, `argv[1] == firstname` and `argv[2] == lastname` and `argv[3] == NULL`, Note this time `argc == 3` (`argv[argc]` means `argv[3]` == NULL).

   For example to print all arguments, you can write you code like:

   ```
     int i = 1;
     printf("Process name is: %s", argv[0]);
     while(argv[i]){// terminates when argv[i] == NULL
       printf("argv[%d] %s\n", argv[i]);   
       i++;
     }
   ```

Do you notice `argv[0]` is always your executable name!  this means whenever you need to print your executable name use `argv[0]` instead of hard code name of your executable while writing code, so that if you recompile and give new name to your executable then `argv[0]` always prints correct name. You should write  code as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  :
  :// some other code
  if(argc < min_number_of_arguments){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: wrong number of arguments passed!\n");
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [first] [second] \n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  :
  :// some other code 
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strcmp()` to compare to `NULL`. Neither argument can be null. In this situation it doesn't make sense anyway. If the argument isn't present, `argc` will be < 3, and if it is somehow empty it will be zero length. Never null.

Comment: Then what is the solution to it??

Comment: @an56k `if(strcmp(argv[2], "") == 0)`

Comment: @an56k you can do like: `i = 1; while(argv[i]){ printf(..); i--}`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'm sorry for that comment without reading the question carefully. And thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you're sure about your line of code? I mean shall it be `i++` in the iteration?

Comment: @PengyuCHEN Yes you are correct it should be `++` instead of `--`.

Comment: Sorry for my down-vote, however it's not true in your answer: `If the argument isn't present, argc will be < 3`. It shall be exactly 3 if OP is passing 2 command line arguments.

Comment: @PengyuCHEN I don't understand. Where do you think we disagree? If argument 2 isn't present, `argc < 3`. If it is present, `argc >= 3`. If the OP is passing exactly 2 arguments, `argc == 3`. There is no disagreement here. What's your point?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shall always use `strcmp(some_string, "")` instead of `strcmp(some_string, NULL)` to check if a string is empty.

However in your problem you shall test

```
if (argc < 4)
```

That's because the executable itself is also in the array `argv`. Consider you're invoking something like `./a.out param0 param1`, then `argc` would be `3` and `argv[0]="./a.out"`, `argv[1]="param0"`, `argv[2]="param1"`.

**EDITED:**

Also, never test `if(strcmp(argv[2], NULL) == 0)` directly. Always test `argc` first. Since there is no grantee that what value would be stored in `argv[argc+n]` for `n >= 0`

Comment: Actually, the language explicitly guarantees that `argv[argc]` is going to be a null pointer. So, testing for number of arguments can be done in two different ways: 1) through `argc`, 2) by looking for the first null entry in `argv[]`.

Comment: Never test `strcmp(argv[2], NULL)` at all. It cannot possibly work. Neither argument can be null.