# How to write a "argv" and "argc"

Tags: c, argv, argc

I understand what argv and argc do and how they're used, but I am in need to recreate them. In C, how would you write a function to imitate them.

Comment: Are you under impression that `argv` and `argc` are just magic variables ? Something like perl's `ARGV` ?

Comment: `argv` is an array of strings (an array of character pointers) and `argc` is the length of that array. So recreating them is just a matter of making an array of strings. What do you want to use the `argc` and `argv` for?

Comment: Read [How to use argv and argc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108368/segmentation-fault-with-strcmp/19108878#19108878)

Comment: I need to do exactly what argv and arc do, but inside a program. When you type in a string of chars, the first string will be the command with the following strings being the arguments, with argc keeping count. 

I understand that you can not modify argc and argv after the program has been started, so I need to create a function that does imitates them.

Answer (score 6):

You just create an array to store the parameters to pass in as `argv`, and set `argc` accordingly, something like;

```
int argc = 3;
char* argv[argc + 1];

argv[0] = "binary name";
argv[1] = "first parameter";
argv[2] = "second parameter";
argv[3] = NULL;

int result = main(argc, argv);
```

Comment: I don't know how many argc I will have, it will be read in by the user, and they should not have white spaces.

So I know I will need an array of strings. 
I am looking for something like
     int main(){
      char *command[100]
        int cNum = 30;
        getCommand(command, cNum);
        while(strcmp(command[0], "exit")) != 0){
         //Do whatever

    }
    return 0;
}

   void getCommand(command, cnum){
    //do something
}

Comment: @user2808307 I will suggest you to look at `stdarg.h`

Comment: @Arpit - yes in C, no in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`argc` and `argv` are used when you are starting a program from the command line, or want to pass some variables to the program.
`argc` contains the number of arguments and `argv` is an array of pointers to the arguments which are strings.
These arguments to main is

```
main(int argc, char** argv)
```

The syntax `char** argv` declares `argv` to be a pointer to a pointer to a character, that is, a pointer to a character array (a character string)--in other words, an array of character strings. You could also write this as `char* argv[]`.

When you run a program, the array `argv` contains, in order, all the information on the command line when you entered the command (strings are delineated by whitespace), including the command itself. The integer `argc` gives the total number of strings, and is therefore equal to equal to the number of arguments plus one. For example, if you typed

```
a.out -i 2 -g -x 3 4
```

the program would receive

```
argc = 7
argv[0] = "a.out"
argv[1] = "-i"
argv[2] = "2"
argv[3] = "-g"
argv[4] = "-x"
argv[5] = "3"
argv[6] = "4"
```

Comment: Alright, well suppose in my program I need something similar to that.
The first command is obvious what will start the program, and the following arguments are variables to that command.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, the function prototype of the main function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recreate them but you could change their names.

In your main you could type in `int main(int numberOfArguments, char *arrayOfArguments[])` and use `numberOfArguments` as `argc` and `arrayOfArguments` as `argv`.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers were helpful, but confusing.  After figuring this out I want to share what worked for me in a C program.

## The command you want to emulate

```
myTool --verbose --outputdirectory "/home/Chad/output"

.\myTool.exe --verbose --outputdirectory "C:\\Users\\Chad\\output"
```

## Function you want to call

```
// Defined in main.c.
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // ...
}
```

## How to pass arguments to that function

```
#include "main.c"

// Create an array to hold each of the command line arguments.
char* arguments[] = {
  // The first parameter should be the name of the binary.
  "myTool",
  // Single arguments are held in a single string.
  "--verbose",
  // Arguments and their values need to be split into separate strings.
  "--outputdirectory",
  "/home/Chad/output",
  // The last argument should be NULL.
  NULL
};

// The first parameter is the count of the number of arguments in our array minus the ending NULL.
main(4, arguments);
```

## Tips

### Quoting paths with spaces

On the command line you'd quote a parameter that contains spaces like this `myTool --outputdirectory "/home/Chad/out folder"`. When building these arguments you'll be tempted to quote that path in the array like this `"\"/home/Chad/out folder\""`, but avoid adding those double-quotes and their escape characters. You don't need to quote the argument when adding it to the array.

### Directories on Windows

If your Windows path includes backslashes you will need to escape those backslashes like this

```c
char* arguments[] = {
  ...
  "--outputdirectory",
  "C:\\Users\\Chad\\output",
  ...
}
```

### Calling your command line tool with a Node Native Addon

[Tutorial](https://blog.atulr.com/node-addon-guide/)

```
#include "main.c"

Napi::Object InitAll(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  char* arguments[] = {
    "myTool",
    "--verbose",
    "--outputdirectory",
    "/home/Chad/output",
    NULL
  };

  main(4, arguments);

  return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, InitAll);
```